# Append the value(text) of selected option to a textarea with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to determine the selected value of a select list with jQuery, and append that value to a textarea.

How do I do that?

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <a>Enter</a><br />
    <div>
      <textarea>

      </textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="select">
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Option1</option>
  <option value="saab">Option2</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Option3</option>
  <option value="audi">Option4</option>
</select>
</div>


$('#myDiv a').click(function(){
$('#select select').appendTo('#myDiv');
$('#select').css('display','block');
       $('#select select').attr('selected').html().clone().appendTo('textarea');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dmymQ/24/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this

HTML

```
 <div id="myDiv">
 <a>Enter</a><br />
 <div>
  <textarea>

  </textarea>
 </div>
 </div>
<input type="button" onclick="apv();" value="A1BC" id="ABCA"/>
<div id="select">
<select id="abc1">
  <option value="volvo">Option1</option>
  <option value="saab">Option2</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Option3</option>
  <option value="audi">Option4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#myDiv a').click(function(){
 $('#select select').appendTo('#myDiv');
 $('#select').css('display','block');
   $('#select select').attr('selected').html().clone().appendTo('textarea'); 
 });

$("#ABCA").click(function()
{
  var text1 = $('#abc1 option:selected').val();
  $('#myDiv textarea').html(text1);
  alert(text1);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dmymQ/40/)

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
var text = $('#select option:selected').text().appendTo('textarea');
```

Comment: `.appendTo(target)` will append a jQuery element to the end of the target - a `string` isn't a jQuery element so this isn't going to work.

Comment: Sorry I worded that badly. I wasn't saying that the target couldn't be a string.

Comment: This is an incorrect way of setting the content of a textarea. Why was this upvoted three times?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't clone a text string, only elements.
2. You can't append a text string, only a jQuery object. To set the html or text, you have to use the methods `.html()` or `.text()`

Solution:

```
// store textarea
var $ta = $('#myDiv textarea');

$('#myDiv a').click(function(){
    $('#select select').appendTo('#myDiv');
    $('#select').css('display','block');

    // get selected option text, not value
    // for value, use .val() instead of .text()
    var text = $('#myDiv select').find(':selected').text();

    // append selected value after a space
    $ta.text($ta.text() + ' ' + text);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/mF5GV/

Answer (score -1):

$('select option:selected');

We use the :selected selector to determine which option is currently selected

Answer (score -1):

Is this one you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/V2cXf/

```
$('#myDiv a').click(function(){
    $('textarea').append($('#select select').val())
});
```